# Query Parameter Binding in DateTime Function of Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using python and attempting to insert into a sqlite3 table as follows:

```
database.execute("INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES (?, ?, DATETIME('now','+? seconds'), ?);", (id, statement, time_duration, access))
```

I get the following exception:

```
ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 4 supplied.
```

I believe this is because for some reason the query parameter binding is not being recognized or expanded in `DATETIME('now','+? seconds);`. This works fine if I hardcode +60 seconds or such in the query.

Is there any way to get sqlite3 to insert the supplied binding there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?` placeholder must be concatenated like this:

```
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE VALUES (?, ?, DATETIME('now', ? || ' seconds'), ?);
```

`+` is not needed in this case.

Also it's a good practice to include the column names in the same order as the values supplied:

```
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE(col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?, ?, DATETIME('now', ? || ' seconds'), ?);
```